# Is there any way to save a search in Xcode or OS X?

Tags: macos, search, automation, regex, xcode

I want to improve my workflow by having a saved search that I can either simply open, or would automatically update. For my current particular use (may change in the future), it would search the contents of files for any text matching the regex `/\/\/\s*((TODO)|(FIXME)):/`, so I can find any comments I or a coworker has made in hopes of returning to the code later. **Is there any way to have a search saved to be easily/automatically performed?**

Anything that's easy to access will work (Xcode-native pre-saved search that I can click to perform, Yosemite sidebar widget that contains the first `n`results, a low-to-no-interaction terminal program that I can keep open on my second monitor, etc.). I know that Finder can have Smart Folders and such, but I would then have to sift through the files, opening each individually to find out if it's code I care about. **I'm really only interested in the found text and the rest of the line it's on**, not what file it's in. It'd be even more awesome if I could get alerts when a new result is found.

Comment: Click on the little arrow thingie by the search box and you can select from the last several search arguments.

Comment: @DanielRHicks often, I am doing dozens of similar searches (like `Delegate`, `ActionDelegate`, `\w+?Delegate`, etc.), which fills that up quickly between needs for this saved search which rarely changes, if ever.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: The "little thingie" is a magnification glass :-) Ben: there are tools like Alfred which have a pasteboard history. Maybe that's something you could utilize?

Comment: @ThomasKilian how so?

Comment: Alfred (and other similar apps) have a feature to search the paste buffer history. So you could find the string and paste is back.

Comment: @ThomasKilian could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible in Xcode 15.0+.

First, use Find in Files in Xcode and customize your search.

Then, in the Search sidebar, click any of the results and you'll see an entry that says `Bookmark "Find 'search text here'`. It's a very useful addition.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this short terminal command will help:

```
while true; do clear; egrep -rhn 'TODO|FIXME' .; sleep 5; done
```

To explain, the while loop will re-run the given commands and then `sleep` for `5` seconds and `clear` refreshes the screen before executing again. `egrep` searches with the provided RegEx through files `-r` recursively in the `.` current directory, `-h` removes filename headers from output (just remove the h if you want those), and `-n` prepends the corresponding line numbers.

You should be able to replace the string I provided with your own RegEx and also replace the `.` with whichever directory you would like to search in.

An alternative, if you have Brew installed, you can use `brew install watch` and run this command instead:

```
watch -x egrep -rhn 'TODO|FIXME' .
```

The `watch` command repeatedly `-x` executes the given command at a default interval.

It looks like watch will only show you one terminal's height worth of matches, unfortunately. In that case, it would be best to just run `egrep` by itself. Watch and egrep have many options which may help you further customize this, and maybe make a full-fledged script out of it. More details for these can be found in the man pages (e.g. `man watch`).

Comment: `-bash: watch: command not found`

Comment: I apologize, I had installed `watch` with Brew. I'll update the answer with an alternative more native to bash.

Comment: will this search subfolders, too?

Comment: Yep. That's what the `-r` option does.

Comment: It hasn't really worked for me, mostly due to crashes and being too busy to get it streamlined. Will get back to you.